# How do I build an Expression Tree for string interpolation?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I have a template which is stored as a string: "[u1:firstname] [u1:lastname]"

I need to convert the template to an `Expression` that outputs a string.
I've already written a parser to pull out the tokens but I'm not quite sure how to build an `Expression` for it. The code has been simplified below.

```
public class Account {
    private Func<Account, string> template;

    public User User1 { get; set; }
    public User User2 { get; set; }
    public string AccountName => this.template(this);

    public void SetTemplate(Expression<Func<Account, string>> template) {
        this.template = template.Compile();
    }
}

public class User {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

The name of an account is defined by the template, and if the properties associated with the template change, so does the account name.

If I set the expression manually it works:
`var account = new Account().SetTemplate(a => $"{a.User1.FirstName} {a.User2.LastName}");`

But how do I build that `Expression` more dynamically?

Right now I'm doing something like this:

```
using TemplateExpression = Expression<Func<Account, string>>;

string templateString = "[u1:firstname] [u1:lastname]";
var expressions = new List<Expression>();
for (int i = 0; i < templateString.Length; ++i) {
    var token = getToken(templateString, i);
    switch (token) {
        case "u1:firstname":
           TemplateExpression u1FirstNameExpr = a => a.User1.FirstName;
           expressions.Add(u1FirstNameExpr);
           break;
        case "u1:lastname":
           TemplateExpression u1LastNameExpr = a => a.User1.LastName;
           expressions.Add(u1LastNameExpr);
           break;
        // other possible tokens.
        default: // constant
           var constant = Expression.Constant(token);
           expressions.Add(constant);
           break;
    }
}
```

But I have no idea how to combine those expressions into one expression that resembles the string interpolation above. I thought about maybe combining the expressions using `string.Concat` instead, but I couldn't get that to work either. Would maybe `string.Format` work better? But I'm still not sure how to construct that Expression.

Comment: That's fine,  I still should be able to use concat or format, but I can't figure it out...

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you're doing and a detailed explanation of what specifically you're having trouble with, you are much less likely to get a good, useful answer. That said, since the C# language feature string interpolation is simply a compile-time syntactic sugar for `string.Format()`, it seems to me that if you're trying to emulate that, that would be the way to go. Convert your tokens to property look-ups, then replace references in the template with `"{0}"`, `"{1}"`, etc. You could even easily extend the idea to support format specifiers if needed.

Comment: And in case I wasn't clear enough: the new expression is just a call expression, calling `string.Format()`, where the arguments are those you'd pass to `string.Format()`.

Comment: What is `templateString`, is it a `string` or is it an array of something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I had to rewrite the `getToken` to be able to test the method. I'm using `Expression.Invoke` because it is the easiest method to call an `Expression` from another `Expression`. In the end nearly all the code is the preparation of a `string` containing the format like `"Hello {0} world {1}"` and the array of objects that are passed in the `string.Format`.

```
public static string getToken(string templateString, ref int i, out bool isToken)
{
    int j = i;

    if (templateString[j] == '{')
    {
        isToken = true;

        j++;

        int k = templateString.IndexOf('}', j);

        if (k == -1)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        i = k + 1;

        return templateString.Substring(j, k - j);
    }
    else
    {
        isToken = false;
        i++;
        return templateString[j].ToString();
    }
}

public static Expression<Func<Account, string>> CreateTemplate(string templateString)
{
    var formatObjs = new List<Expression>();
    var formatString = new StringBuilder();
    int parameterNumber = 0;

    var accountParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Account), "a");

    for (int i = 0; i < templateString.Length;)
    {
        bool isToken;
        var token = getToken(templateString, ref i, out isToken);

        if (isToken)
        {
            Expression<Func<Account, string>> member;

            switch (token)
            {
                case "u1:firstname":
                    member = a => a.User1.FirstName;
                    break;
                case "u1:lastname":
                    member = a => a.User1.LastName;
                    break;
                // other possible tokens.
                default: // constant
                    throw new Exception();
            }

            formatObjs.Add(Expression.Invoke(member, accountParameter));

            formatString.Append('{');
            formatString.Append(parameterNumber);
            formatString.Append('}');
            parameterNumber++;
        }
        else
        {
            formatString.Append(token);
        }
    }

    var formatMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Format", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new[] { typeof(string), typeof(object[]) }, null);
    var formatConstantExpression = Expression.Constant(formatString.ToString());
    var formatObjsExpression = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(object), formatObjs);
    var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Account, string>>(Expression.Call(formatMethod, formatConstantExpression, formatObjsExpression), accountParameter);
    return lambdaExpression;
}
```

Use it like:

```
var acc = new Account
{
    User1 = new User { FirstName = "Foo", LastName = "Bar" }
};

acc.SetTemplate(Account.CreateTemplate("Hello {u1:firstname} World {u1:lastname}!!!"));
string name = acc.AccountName;
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. I almost had it too. I was missing Expression.NewArrayInit. I was just trying to pass in the expression list (formatObjs in your example).

Comment: @RabidPenguin Did the same in a previous iteration of the code :-) The fact that thanks to `params` the array creation of `string.Format` is implicit in C# deceived me too.